# Including and Excluding Filter values based on a particular criteria

Tags: tableau-api

Attached is the mock data on which we are trying to do the following :

We have **Configuration Id** : which is a part of a car like dashboard of the car or tyres etc.
Then we have **part attachments** which tells you about the parts that make up an entire configuration. For eg : 'head lights', 'rear lights' and 'fog lamps' make up 'Lights'.

[image]

*Problem Statement* : We need to have 2 filters : Part attachment included and excluded such that, when **part attachments included** is selected as steering then I get 3 rows(marked in yellow in column E) based on selection. But in the **part attachments excluded** filter, we don't want the configuration id where the part attachment = 'Headlight'. This means that row no 17 should be eliminated when filtering gout headlamps from the filter.

So basically when part attachment excluded filter excludes 'headlight' then data in row no 17 should not be show in tableau.

I found this a little difficult to implement using normal filters in tableau.

Comment: what is logic to decide part is included or excluded?

Comment: If for eg, steering is selected in include and headlight is selected in exclude filter then the steering which has configuration id as ETC should not be shown and all other values must be present

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Using normal filter you won't be able to achieve this, Try below method:

Create two parameters:

Include and exclude and take the respective database fields using the list radio button.

Now create 2 calcualted fields:

Include:

```
Parameter1 = Databasefield
```

Exclude:

```
Parameter2= database field
```

Now when placing the two parameters on to filters for include select `True` and for Exclude select `False`

Comment: Hey Srikanth, we want the entire configuration id to disappear when a particular part attachment is excluded

Comment: @KapilLehar couldn't understand exact requirement